# How can I transfer files between two Ubuntu computers on a LAN without installing additional software?

Tags: networking, sync, file-sharing

I know I can install Samba or openssh-server to be able to share files between two Ubuntu computers. Is there a way to share files *without* installing additional packages?

I installed Ubuntu on two systems on the same LAN, but without Internet connectivity. I found that my usual way of transferring files (scp) failed because openssh-server was not installed on either system. Using Personal File Sharing was impossible without installing extra packages. I ended up using netcat to transfer, which is suboptimal and not intuitive for the average user.

So I'd like to know if anyone knows of a way to do this with out-of-the-box Ubuntu installations (or at least, with packages available in the Ubuntu desktop CD).

Thanks!

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/326211/best-way-to-transfer-files-over-a-lan-between-two-linux-computers

Comment: Ubuntu and Windows: http://askubuntu.com/questions/107208/how-to-transfer-files-between-ubuntu-and-windows/781941#781941

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can move to a given directory with `cd`, then serve the current directory as a web server with the command:

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer
```

On the other machine go to the address `http://server-ip:8000/`

where "server-ip" is what you see when you do "ifconfig" on the source computer, under "inet addr:". For example, if the output of ifconfig on the source computer starts like this:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:30:67:d5:a7:a4  
          inet addr:10.0.0.3  Bcast:10.0.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          ...
```

then on the target computer, you should point the browser to:

```
 http://10.0.0.3:8000/
```

Comment: Thanks for this! I found this the easiest way to do what I need, just open a terminal, type a relatively simple command, and I can use the browser on the other system.

Comment: thanks, this is the most easiest way to download files from other computers. Is there a way to speed up the transfer rate, currently i am getting only 2.5 MB/sec.

Comment: Beware that in Python 3 `SimpleHTTPServer` has been renamed to `http.server`.

Answer (score 1):

if you want something faster that python's `SimpleHTTPServer` module (which is awesome and is most simple way imho), you can use netcat (`nc` utility) - it's using raw TCP so you won't be having overhead that comes with HTTP protocol.

For example if you are trying to copy file `config.xml` from host germany.local to host france.local (both running ubuntu), you need to follow these steps:

1. on target host france.local run:

   ```
   nc -l -p 7000 > copied_config.xml
   ```

   (it will start nc process that listens on the port 7000 for incoming data and writes said data to file `copied_config.xml`)
2. on source host germany.local run:

   ```
   nc -q 0 france.local 7000 < config.xml
   ```

That's all!

Also, you can check [this helpful howto](http://www.microhowto.info/howto/copy_a_file_from_one_machine_to_another_using_netcat.html) for more in depth instructions

Comment: Thanks! If you read the question you'll notice it's what I did back then, and my comment was that it's `suboptimal and not intuitive for the average user.`  I still prefer SimpleHTTPServer as it implies one command on the sending end and a browser on the "client" end which is super easy to use.