# How to transfer files between Ubuntu and Windows?

Tags: networking, windows, file-sharing

I wanna transfer some files from this PC with Ubuntu to a PC with Windows 7 I don't care how to do it (ftp, samba or whatever) I wanna know the steps, I searched a lot but I can't find anything that works. Thank you.

Comment: Related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/310180/how-to-share-files-using-a-wireless-network

Answer (score 43, accepted):

### Share Folders in Ubuntu 11.10

**Objectives**: Share a folder in Ubuntu and access it from Windows

To get started,  right-click on the folder you wish to share and select ‘Sharing Options’

[image: screenshot]

When prompted to install Samba services, do it.

[image: screenshot]

After installing Samba services, click ‘Restart session’

[image: screenshot]

Then click ‘Create Share’ to complete the process.

[image: screenshot]

> Open **Terminal** Replace USERNAME with your account name.

```
sudo smbpasswd -a USERNAME

sudo cp /etc/samba/smb.conf /etc/samba/smb.conf.old
sudo nano /etc/samba/smb.conf
```

scroll to the global section, and add the lines

```
encrypt passwords = true 
wins support = yes
```

press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd> and <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> to save, and exit nano

```
sudo service smbd restart

On the Windows machine, go to Start –> All Programs –> Accessories –> run and type the command:

\\computer_name\share_name
```

computer name can be ip address of ubuntu machine , to check ip of ubuntu machine , go to ubuntu machine & open terminal & type ifconfig

[image: screenshot]

Type the Ubuntu computer name and the share name of the resource.

You will get a prompted to enter your credentials.  Type your Ubuntu username and password and click ‘OK’

[image: screenshot]

Now try again to access the shares from your Windows machine

[image: screenshot]

### Transfer files From Ubuntu To Windows

On Ubuntu Machine install openssh-server

```
sudo apt-get install openssh-server
```

after installing go to windows machine & download / install [FileZilla](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9oE27.jpg)  & open it

[image: screenshot]

- **Host** = Ubuntu Machine Ip address
- **Username** = Your Ubuntu Machine Username
- **Password** = You Username Password
- **Port** = 22

**Done** Now you can easily transfer files from Windows to Ubuntu OR Ubuntu to windows

Comment: Instructions worked flawlessly, transferring files now when my USB stick failed because of it's size.

Comment: More than two years later, still works like a charm (Ubuntu 12.04 to Windows 7).

Comment: On Windows 10, for the first method, I found that the run prompt wouldn't do anything with the path I was giving it. You can however, open Explorer and click the Network link on the left, then find the hostname of the Ubuntu PC and it will show all shared folders.

Comment: Thanks, it works but the transfer rate is very slow for me (max 150KBytes/s). Can I make it faster? I can download files at 5MBytes/s from internet.

Comment: Sharing folder working on Ubuntu 22.04 to Windows 10. I just used the IP of my ubuntu machine to connect to the folder from windows 10. `\\xxx.xxx.xx.xx\folder_name`

Answer (score 18):

### HTTP server

[HTTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol) is the protocol used to access regular websites, so every OS was forced to implement it!

Find your IP on the source computer, e.g. `192.168.0.10`. On Ubuntu:

```
ip addr
```

Create a server in a directory that contains the file you want to transfer, Python 3:

```
python3 -m http.server 8080
```

or Python 2:

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8080
```

On the receiving computer, open a browser, and visit:

```
192.168.0.10:8080
```

Now you can navigate through directories to the file you want.

I'm not sure if this method is fast / robust, but it is one of the simplest to setup and portable.

Faster alternatives are discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12905426/what-is-a-faster-alternative-to-pythons-simplehttpserver).

### `rsync`

Just setup an [SSH server on Windows](https://serverfault.com/questions/8411/what-is-a-good-ssh-server-to-use-on-windows), and then you can use `rsync` on Ubuntu to copy files in either direction. Full CLI goodness.

It might be possible to run [rsync on Windows as well](https://superuser.com/questions/300263/how-to-use-rsync-from-windows-pc-to-remote-linux-server).

I have described the Ubuntu to Ubuntu `rsync` usage in more detail at: [How to share files through the local network?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/310180/how-to-share-files-through-the-local-network/1089904#1089904)

Comment: For a single file, another similar approach is `woof`.

Answer (score 3):

There is a free file manager with GUI [WinSCP](https://winscp.net/eng/index.php). You can copy files in one click.

[image]

After creating connection you have one panel with your local computer and a panel with a remote computer.