# Sharing file between Ubuntu & Window

Tags: sharing

I had problem with sharing file between Window & Ubuntu
I have 12 PC use window connect to 1 PC using win 7 as a server (call SERVER). And I have 1 laptop use Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, also connect to that SERVER PC.
Everything is OK, perfect. I can connect by Samba, well done. I like.
The problem is UBUNTU PC after 15 or 20 minutes, connection to SERVER PC break, can not connect. If I restart SERVER PC, then everything will be OK again.
There are something wrong, pls help me. Thank you

Henry

Comment: What software are you using to transfer the file? Have you tried with [NitroShare](https://launchpad.net/nitroshare)? It is pretty simple and straightforward

Comment: I used Files in Ubuntu connect to Windows. While connection break, still I can  ping to that PC SERVER. The sharing work well between Win PC together.

Comment: In the meantime, check out [this post](http://askubuntu.com/q/107208/62483). You could find some useful info there

Comment: Thank you! I read, but nothing help, because, I can connect and transfer file properly. The problem is the connection will be broken after sometime. That is my point. Until I restart SERVER PC, then connect can establish again.