# Transferring files from Ubuntu to Windows

Tags: samba, transfer

Tried to use the method suggested here [How to transfer files between Ubuntu and Windows?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/107208/how-to-transfer-files-between-ubuntu-and-windows)
Where i installed samba in the ubuntu. Everything went fine except when it came to accepting the username and password on the windows, the windows is not accepting the ubuntu password. What to do?

Comment: You need to log into the windows machine with the windows username and password.