# How to uninstall samba on ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, samba

I was enabling file sharing using this question 
[How to transfer files between Ubuntu and Windows?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/107208/how-to-transfer-files-between-ubuntu-and-windows)
and something went wrong so I couldn't click on dialog buttons to install some service after samba. So samba got intalled and other service didn't so I couldn't complete all steps from tutorial and file sharing doesn't work.

So I want to uninstall samba and complete the tutorial again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is what you are after :)

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge samba
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks, it worked. I tried to install file sharing again and got some system error dialog, thus it fails to install libpam-smbpass, probably a bug

Comment: Unfortunately this is where my knowledge hits its limitations, my sharing is simply set up with all files stored on a separate ntfs partition.