# Aiming to transfer a very large amount of data from an Ubuntu 18.04 PC to a WIN10 PC. What should I be using?

Tags: networking, windows, samba, file-sharing, openssh

I need to **transfer** a *reasonably large amount* of data from an **Ubuntu 18.04 to a Windows**. I have checked the other Q/As ([[1]](https://askubuntu.com/questions/107208/how-to-transfer-files-between-ubuntu-and-windows),[[2]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12905426/what-is-a-faster-alternative-to-pythons-http-server-or-simplehttpserver)) on this site but what I have gathered is inconclusive.

People suggest using either *SambaShare*, *OpenSSH*, or *SimpleHTTPServer*. The thing is, comments describe some methods as slow which would be impractical for my purpose.

So I want to know what would the fastest and most reliable method to transfer my data (multiple files) be. :))

Edit: The devices are on the same network. Also, this is a one time thing.

Ref: [[1]](https://askubuntu.com/questions/107208/how-to-transfer-files-between-ubuntu-and-windows)
     [[2]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12905426/what-is-a-faster-alternative-to-pythons-http-server-or-simplehttpserver)

Comment: Are they in the same location or remote to each other?  Will this be over the internet or a local network?  Can you physically connect them or insert a USB drive?

Comment: If they are on the same LAN or you can connect them directly, use Samba. If they are remote, think about SSH. But because of that additional encryption/decryption it will bring overhead. Also, could you define "reasonably large amount"? Maybe while you wait for an answer any of those methods would have already transferred it in the meantime. You id not say if it is one time action or you would need it regularly.

Comment: @thomasrutter Using a USB drive would be impractical since I cannot possibly get one big enough for the data. It will be over a local network on the same location.

Comment: @marosg They are in the same location, over the same WiFi network. Reasonably large amount would be around 250 Gigs, spread over thousands of files.

Comment: @marosg What transfer speeds should I expect from Samba over a 5 Ghz or 2.4 Ghz WLAN?

Comment: 1. Using a USB 3 HDD would work well, if the HDD is big enough, and 250 GB is a rather small size today for a HDD; 2. Connecting via wire (ethernet) is more reliable and faster compared to wifi/wlan, but both network connections should work.

Comment: Going to go in for the SMB via WLAN as an HDD/Ethernet is impractical due to availability. @sudodus

Comment: And thank you, everyone here, for helping me on this.

Comment: Huh? I have a 2TB USB drive. If you're transferring 250GB much data you will save days or weeks going direct as opposed to wifi. 
I can't remember who said "never underestimate the bandwidth of a box of hard drives in a  station wagon" or some such. A fast networked option would be wired gigabit ethernet with FTP. USB drive using USB3 would be reasonable.