# File transfer between Ubuntu and Windows system

Tags: networking, dual-boot, file-sharing

I have 2 computers connected through Ethernet, both computers are dual booted with Ubuntu studio 20.04 and Windows 7 64 bit. I  set up primary settings like samba, network manager, IP address, etc.

Now I am able to share files when the systems are under Ubuntu to Ubuntu or Windows to Windows. But I am unable to do that under Ubuntu-Windows or vice-versa.

That is true, no matter which system is on Ubuntu/Windows. I find it difficult to perform cross-OS file sharing. I have no experience in networking.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to transfer files between Ubuntu and Windows?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/107208/how-to-transfer-files-between-ubuntu-and-windows)

Comment: Tried the above link....tried to access ubuntu machine from win machine through FileZilla.....Filezilla says this.....FATAL ERROR:Network error:Network is unreachable......ok.....Where to start the trouble shooting?......There must be some basic problem with my set up......

Comment: Ip address was 192.168.72.8....pinged from win command prompt....."transmit failed.general failure "....was the message

Comment: Yes , Sure,  address of the Ubuntu machine is 192.168.72.8,I can access this machine from the first machine when it  run ubuntu

Comment: You should check [possible reasons](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=transmit+failed.general+failure) (yes, there are many…) and try to find your point of failure. I am sorry but it’s pretty inefficient to continue in guessing as I’ve done.

Comment: Will try your suggestions..Thank you for your time

Comment: You are dual booting, are you sure you are getting the same IPs on a given computer regardless of if you boot win or linux there? I would check that first. Because `I can access this machine from the first machine when it run ubuntu` does not mean anything

Comment: Let me be more specific. Machine A runs windows , machine B runs ubuntu. The IP add of machine B is 192.168.72.8 ....This Machine B is not accessible from machine A(windows). But B is accessible from A , if A is on ubuntu. Incidentally, B is acessible from A if both runs windows. In this case , of course B gets different ip address automatically (windows-windows case)

Comment: Update: While machine A remain in windows , I booted machine B to windows. Windows allotted auto IP for machine B...That was 169.254.195.214.  Now I boot back B again to linux and I put this IP address to B.    Now I am able to ping from A to B successfully ,  it failed earlier.  Now .. A small step forward. Any suggestion what to do next? BTW, is it right to do what I did ?

Comment: Start with setting permanent, static IP addresses on both machines, in both OSes (Linux and Windows).

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question:
In theory, any IP address should work, but in practice, it is not so.
After tried various numbers, I find the following tutorial-ish number worked for me.

```
IP 192.168.1.1 mask 255.255.255.0 gateway 192.168.1.2 Dns servers 208.67.222.222,208.67.220.220 for machine A
IP 192.168.1.2 mask 255.255.255.0 gateway 192.168.1.1 Dns servers 208.67.222.222,208.67.220.220 for machine B
```

Each machine assigned to the same address in both OSes.
Now file transfer in both directions is possible, irrespective of which machine run on which OS.
Even media streaming is so smooth. Thanks for helping hands.
MY PROBLEM IS SOLVED.

Comment: I am glad you solved it! Hadn’t you used a mask with values different from 0 and 255 before? I guess it’s the most error-prone part of the settings.