# Copy share a file between Xubuntu Virtual Machine and Windows 8.1 host in VirtalBox WITHOUT Guest add-ons

Tags: windows, xubuntu, virtualbox, virtualization, transfer

### Ubuntu!

**TL;DR at the bottom**
I'm on a Windows 8.1 host. I installed Xubuntu 14.04 on a virtual machine in Oracle's VirtualBox. The guest add-ons couldn't install properly. The CD shows all the time when I press the button to add the guest add-ons however I'm only able to access it at random times O_o. I'm rather new to Linux/virtualization but know to open a command winnow inside the CD directory and type in *sudo sh VBoxLinuxAdditions.run* in order to install the VBox Linux addons. That's what I did when the CD was accessible to me. The installation seemed ok so I restarted the system. It didn't work but I didn't really care because I was switching to a confortable resolution from Xubuntu's Display options.
My problem lies here: I have gotten my hands on some 10 GBs of files inside of my Xubuntu guest. I'd like to be able to transfer them to my Windows 8.1 host without any VBox Linux guest add-ons. Anyone can please help me to find out how to tat? It would be really appreciated to a complete newbie that is really ambitious to find out why Linux is better and safer to encourage a lot of people to use it! :)

Thank you very much!

**TL;DR** : How can I transfer files from a Xubuntu 14.04 LTS Oracle VirtualBox virtual machine guest to a Windows 8.1 host **without** the Linux guest add-ons. Thank you!

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5906441/how-to-ssh-to-a-virtualbox-guest-externally-through-a-host.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to transfer files without any difficult setup, install ssh-server on your xubuntu and use an sFTP client (e.g. FileZilla) on your windows to drag and pull files.

You can also use putty's pscp if you prefer command line

You can set up SAMBA shares on your Xubuntu, but this requires some additional software and configuration.
You can set up NFS shares on your Xubuntu as well, as Windows 8 comes standard with NFS utils.
You can use Teamviewer ... 
You can use join.me ... 
You can use Skype ...
You can use so many different tools :)

The easiest way I believe however, is using FileZilla over SSH.
If you have specific questions about a certain tool, please reply or have a look around on askubuntu.com. Many of them have been covered already.

Comment: +1 - there's also python's SimpleHTTPServer as mentioned here: [How can I transfer files between two Ubuntu computers on a LAN without installing additional software?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/95573/how-can-i-transfer-files-between-two-ubuntu-computers-on-a-lan-without-installin)

Comment: one nice piece of software that I forgot to mention, is BTSync. This is a p2p software that keeps folders in sync between different devices. Instead of copying to and from a machine, you can simply copy or move the data to the BTSync folder(s) and they'll be synced in realtime to any other device that subscribes to those folders.